WinUI3 Datagrid TemplatedColumn with flyout button
I'm developing a WinUI3 application. I'd like to have a CommunityToolkit datagrid with a button column each row. When the button is clicked a flyout needs to show up letting user enters the data to populate that field.
For simplicity I put only two buttons in the example but the application will require more controls:
<controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value" IsReadOnly="True">
    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Button Content="{Binding Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Button.Flyout>
                        <Flyout>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="All items will be removed. Do you want to continue?" Margin="0,0,0,12" />
                                <Button Content="Yes, empty my cart" Click="Button_Click" />
                                <Button Content="No, cart is full" Click="FullButton_Click" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Flyout>
                    </Button.Flyout>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>

Gif
As shown in the gif I've got clicking focus issues. First click works like a charm, further clicking seems to put cell in edit mode and flyout is not triggered. If I change the focus on other rows / cells results are different each time.
I think there's an editing / click pass through mechanism that I don't know how to avoid. Putting cell in "IsReadOnly" mode doesn't change the behaviour.
If I try to use a MenuFlyout or ContextFlyout on the cell it works great, but I need to show more controls and not a simple menu to be triggered on right click.

The DataGridComboBoxColumn used to have the same issue and you can see here how it was fixed.
You can create a custom DataGrid and Column and apply a similar fix like this:
UPDATE
I updated my answer in way that you can cancel the edit mode explictly when the Flyout is closed.
public class DataGridButtonWithFlyoutColumn : DataGridTemplateColumn
{
    public event EventHandler<object>? FlyoutClosed;

    protected override object PrepareCellForEdit(FrameworkElement editingElement, RoutedEventArgs editingEventArgs)
    {
        if (editingElement is Button button)
        {
            button.Flyout.ShowAt(button);
            button.Flyout.Closed += (s, e) =>
            {
                this.FlyoutClosed?.Invoke(this, e);
            };
        }

        return base.PrepareCellForEdit(editingElement, editingEventArgs);
    }
}

public class DataGridEx : DataGrid
{
    public DataGridEx()
    {
        this.BeginningEdit += DataGridEx_BeginningEdit;
    }

    private void DataGridEx_BeginningEdit(object? sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column is DataGridButtonWithFlyoutColumn column)
        {
            column.FlyoutClosed += DataGridButtonWithFlyoutColumn_FlyoutClosed;
        }
    }

    private void DataGridButtonWithFlyoutColumn_FlyoutClosed(object? sender, object e)
    {
        _ = CancelEdit();

        if (sender is DataGridButtonWithFlyoutColumn column)
        {
            column.FlyoutClosed -= DataGridButtonWithFlyoutColumn_FlyoutClosed;
        }
    }
}

and use it like this:
<local:DataGridEx
    x:Name="DataGridControl"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}">
    <toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
        <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn
            Binding="{Binding Name}"
            Header="Name" />
        <toolkit:DataGridComboBoxColumn
            Binding="{Binding Type}"
            Header="Type"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind Types, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <local:DataGridButtonWithFlyoutColumn Header="Value">
            <local:DataGridButtonWithFlyoutColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="LightGreen">
                        <TextBlock
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            Text="{Binding Value}" />
                    </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>
            </local:DataGridButtonWithFlyoutColumn.CellTemplate>
            <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Background="HotPink"
                        Content="{Binding Value}"
                        FontWeight="ExtraBold">
                        <Button.Flyout>
                            <Flyout>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock
                                        Margin="0,0,0,12"
                                        Text="All items will be removed. Do you want to continue?" />
                                    <Button
                                        Click="Button_Click"
                                        Content="Yes, empty my cart" />
                                    <Button
                                        Click="Button_Click_1"
                                        Content="No, cart is full" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Flyout>
                        </Button.Flyout>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </local:DataGridButtonWithFlyoutColumn>
    </toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
</local:DataGridEx>


Thanks a lot, this way flyout shows up every time cell enters into edit mode. Unfortunately if the cell is already in edit mode continuous clicking gives the same issue., like button wouldn't trigger the flyout. I tried register for click event and do a Flyout.ShowAt with no luck.

You are right. I updated my answer in way that you can cancel the edit mode explictly when the Flyout is closed.

Thanks again for updating your answer. Works good. I find quite silly the need of overriding a DataGrid just to let the button works. I mean, i'm in edit mode, button is created and ontop and should get clicks.
